# C++ call different class constructors, avoid switch

Tags: c++, constructor, switch-statement

I'm capturing a network packet in my program as a `char*` array. The first byte of the array represents the type of packet I received and for each type I want to have a separate child class of my generic `Packet` base class to which I pass the byte array and where it will be interpreted.

I would like to avoid using a switch statement where the packet's first byte would be evaluated and the according constructor called. Firstly because in OOP you should avoid switch clauses and secondly because I don't want to add a separate case to the switch statement every time I add a packet class.

I looked into the Factory Method pattern, but I'm not sure how that would help me in this situation or if it would solve my problem at all.

Basically what I want to avoid is editing my code at 10 different places just to add a single packet class.

Comment: The factory pattern will not avoid the switch but instead it will encapsulate the switch, that it will only occur once!

Comment: You're determining the type at run-time, so you *have* to use a runtime construct, like a switch of if-else ladder. Don't be too attached to phrases like "in OOP you should avoid switch clauses". I think the most elegant solution is to have a map of function-pointers, pointing to factory functions. One for each child-type, the key being the byte-value that you read from the char-array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the packet type is *always* exactly one byte, then you can create simple lookup table, like so:

```
struct Packet { virtual ~Packet() {} /* ... */ };   // and abstract

std::map<char, std::unique_ptr<Packet>(*)(char const *, std::size_t)> factory;
std::map<char, std::size_t> packet_size;
```

**Example usage:**

```
void handle_input(char const * buf, std::size_t available_size)
{
    if (available_size == 0) { return; }                   // no data

    if (packet_size[buf[0]] > available_size) { return }   // not enough data

    auto p = factory[buf[0]](buf, available_size);         // create packet

    // process p
    // reduce available size by packet_size[buf[0]]
}
```

**Implementation:**

```
struct Type05Packet : Packet
{
    static std::unique_ptr<Packet> make(char const * buf, std::size_t len)
    {
        return std::make_unique<Type05Packet>(buf, len);
    }

private:
   Type05Packet(char const * buf, std::size_t len) { /* populate */ }
};
```

And you have to add the factory data (e.g. in `main()`):

```
factory[5] = &Type05Packet::make;   // creation function for packet '5'
packet_size[5] = 20;                // packet '5' is 20 bytes long
```

**Notes:** There are several details you should improve upon.

- The packet creation function should first attempt to parse the data and only call a constructor if the data is valid, otherwise it should return an error condition (e.g. nullptr).
- The factory and size maps could be populated in some kind of self-registering global constructor. They could perhaps also be combined into a single, pair-value map, for consistency.
- The map lookups should use `find(buf[0])` to cater for unrecognized packet types.
- The example usage probably not very realistic. You should be in some kind of situation where you get to pop data off a buffer at your discretion; the point is that you only do that once there's enough data to form an entire packet.

Answer (score 5):

> *"I would like to avoid using a switch statement ..."*

At some point you'll need to discriminate upon this byte, no matter if you're doing so in a factory or elsewhere.

A way to avoid `switch`, is to create a map of `create_class` functions, and find and call these according the map key (the discriminating byte value).

This solution will have the advantage, that you can easily add further keys and `create_class` functions, without changing the basic factory code.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah factory pattern would encapsulate the object creation and you only have to pass it which type of object you want to create ( through string/enum etc. ) One main advantage of factory pattern over normal switch statements is that it localizes object creation at one place.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a jump table.  Allocate an array of function pointers, indexed by something you can key to the message type, and then in the message handler index that array and call the desired function.